# "Requires a valid user is specified ..." error when using getCount

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use `getCount` from [test console](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/dashboard.getCount).

When I enter a `uid` of a user that has installed my application (using basic and `publish_stream` permissions) I get the following error:

```
{
  "error_code": 240,
  "error_msg": "Requires a valid user is specified (either via the session or via the API parameter for specifying the user.",
  "request_args": [
    {
      "key": "uid",
      "value": "REMOVED_USER_ID"
    },
    {
      "key": "method",
      "value": "dashboard.getCount"
    },
    {
      "key": "access_token",
      "value": "REMOVED_ACCESS_TOKEN"
    },
    {
      "key": "format",
      "value": "json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas why is this happenning? How can I fix it? Do I need some extra permissions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

John, you don't need extra permissions. The problem is with your access token. The access token that the tool uses it your personal ***user*** access token and will only work for your uid. If you use the ***application*** access token (meaning APP_ID|APP_SECRET) then you will be able to see the result of this method for all users of your application.

> api.facebook.com/method/dashboard.getCount?uid=**[UID]**&access_token=**[appid|appsecret]**&format=json