# either via the session or via the API parameter for specifying the user

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

I would like to share with another friend's wall. but get the following error

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 240: Requires a valid user is specified (either via the session or via the API parameter for specifying the user.

Answer (score 1):

Next time you should search Google before asking a question.

[The answer to the this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859237/requires-a-valid-user-is-specified-error-when-using-getcount) will give you the answer for this question.

You can find the [Test Console for REST API `user.setstatus` here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.setStatus/) for assistance.